# How to handle and error and send error to respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I'm developing a rails app, just webservices for now..

In one of those webservices I receive a JSON with a lot of users info, for example:

```
"friends": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "10",
        "country": "Ecuador"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": "15",
        "country": "USA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mery",
        "age": "20",
        "country": "Mexico"
    }
]
```

So... in my controller I just loop through each of this "friends" and do something like Friend.new I populate the fields on that object and then save...

But my problem comes at the moment of sending a response to the requester, sometimes this process may fail because a validation fail or something like that... How do I handle this? Do I just do a begin...rescue...end for the loop and then? What do I send to the respond_with? Is it possible to send an respond_with({:error => "Validation problem"})??

What's a good approach to handle this? Any idea?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use respond_with if something goes wrong. For example you can dump errors of not valid object, and set up http status code for this.

```
respond_with(@your_object.errors.messages, :status => :unprocessable_entity)
```

To make it clear try to create new not valid instance and save it. Then cast `errors` method to this instance.

Comment: yes, but i'm going to be saving lots of objects in the same loop, how do I know from outside that loop which object failed?